# Add server-side certificate on Windows

Tags: java, windows, cryptography, digital-signature, p12

I imported a `p12` certificate file to system on `Windows 7`, on which a `Tomcat` webapp is running. I try to retrieve certificate with following code:

```
private KSPrivateKeyEntry getKSPrivateKeyEntry(final String alias, ProtectionParameter passwordProtection) {
  KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore();
  try {
    if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
      final PrivateKeyEntry entry = (PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, passwordProtection);
      return new KSPrivateKeyEntry(alias, entry);
    }
  } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new DSSException("Unable to retrieve key for alias '" + alias + "'", e);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Certificate not present in output and I am not sure, how to use alias for a certificate in a proper way.

Comment: So `entry.getCertificate()` and `entry.getCertificateChain` return `null` or an empty array?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : No, I just can't see some added certificates in output.

Comment: So you want to find certificates that are not part of a certificate chain leading to a private key? Do you know the alias for them? Or any other identifying features?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : I have serial number, but I have p12 file, which is defined in this file too.